# Portable solar-powered .gif frame

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, battery, chromium

Here's a project challenge: looking to create a portable rpi-powered .gif frame similar to [this](http://lifehacker.com/make-an-animated-gif-photo-frame-with-a-raspberry-pi-1658839211), except one that wouldn't require internet connection and would just store the .gif collection on its SD card. Ideas on the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

For the solar power just buy an off the shelf solar phone charger then connect it to a phone backup battery such as one from morphie, for the gif loading you could use some of the tools from image magic. Please install it by typing `apt-get install imagemagick` into your terminal from there you can enter the command `animate mohammadIsAwesome.gif` into the terminal with mohammadIsAwesome.gif being the location of the gif, note that you have to be in an X gui for this to work and that the animation will be border less. To resize the gif to be full screen simply enter 
`animate -resize 1920x1080 myGIF.gif` to resize your gif, note that's width by height.
Furthermore, resizing will probably make a mess of most animated gifs. You need to process them first.

```
convert origionalGIF.gif -coalesce NEWGIF.gif
```

The converted NEWGIF.gif should work properly with `animate -resize 1920x1080 NEWGIF.gif`

What is coalesce: coalesce is when a gif is processed so that each friend will have a fully defined look to form a film strip animation which will although increase file sizes will also optimize the gif to reduce load times, and to reduce cpu usage.

You can read more about other image magic command line options [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php)